# keyboard shortcut to change command and option keys on mac

Tags: macos, bash, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I have a German MacBook, though for programming I largely use an external QWERTY-keyboard with the standard Windows keys. To not confuse my muscle memory I would like to have the `command` and `option` key (respectively on the external keyboard the `windows` and `alt` key) in the same order as on the MacBooks keyboard. However, instead of always going to preferences-->keyboard-->special keys and manually changing the two keys function, I would like to have a keyboard shortcut (similar to the shortcut for changing the input method).

Does anybody have an idea how to do this? I thought of writing a bash script that does the change and then define a keyboard shortcut to the script but neither know what the commands for the script needed to be, nor do I know how to bind a shortcut to a script :/

Thanks for your help!!

Cheeers!!

Answer (score 1):

[This documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2450/_index.html) on Apple Developer's website could be a good start. It explains the usage of the `hidutil` command-line tool which allows to remap keys in this way:

```bsh
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000004,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000004}]}'
```

where you map a source key (`HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc`) and a destination key (`HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst`) using the hexadecimal value of the keys you want to remap.

In the script above I used the same source and destination to issues if anyone copies and pastes the script, but if you want to try it out and remap the `A` key to the `B` key just replace the destination with `0x700000005`, then to reset it run the command above.

In that same page you can find [a table](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2450/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017618-CH1-KEY_TABLE_USAGES) with the hexadecimal value of all keys. The ones you would need are:

- `0xE2` - Left Alt key
- `0xE3` - Left GUI key (⌘ / Windows key)
- `0xE6` - Right Alt key
- `0xE7` - Right GUI key (⌘ / Windows key)

---

Also, you might be interested in looking at [jeantil/autokbisw](https://github.com/jeantil/autokbisw), a small utility which memorizes the keyboard settings for a specific input source and restores them automatically when that same keyboard becomes active again.

There's a [feature request](https://github.com/jeantil/autokbisw/issues/24) for the functionality you're describing, maybe you can have a look and contribute to the project.